# How to create a contract B that calls a library via contract A

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, library

As I understand it, the logic to deploy contract that uses library is as below: supposed that `MetaCoin` contract use `TestLib` library

1. Deploy `TestLib` library first, then get a library contract address
2. Get contract bytecodes that links library address by command `solc --optimize --bin MetaCoin.sol --libraries "TestLib:<address>"`
3. Deploy `MetaCoin` contract by the bycodes

The above is the **direct way** to deploy contract that uses library.

However, how to deploy it in an **indirect way**? in other words, how to create a contract B that uses a library via contract A? How to link library to contract B?